# Access web server on VirtualBox/Vagrant machine from host browser?

Tags: django, virtualbox

I have a Django web server on a VirtualBox/Vagrant machine running Ubuntu.

I have followed this guide to create a Django project: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

I have a web server running at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` inside my guest machine. This is the first time I am running a Django web server. It is supposed to be a hello world app.

How can I access this web application from my host browser?

I have tried running ifconfig in the guest to get the IP that I should visit I found a promising IP address in inet addr.

But I have tried entering the following into my host browser and it didn't work. 
`http://inetaddrnumbers:8000/`

How can I access the web server from my browser?

Comment: Try running the dev server on `0.0.0.0:8000` (`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`) instead. `127.0.0.1` is only accessible from the same machine.

Comment: In addition to the above comment check whether you are allowed to host by your ISP. Generally they block 80 port.

Comment: @kakar: the web server only needs to be accessible from my computers. It doesnt need to be accessible frol the internet, so I hope I dont need to think about the ISP

Comment: @aumo: I tried runnung the server on 0.0.0.0:8000 and the visiting http://inetaddrnumbers:8000/. That didnt work unfortunately.

Comment: How did you configure networking in your VagrantFile?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this.

1. Open the vagrant file (should be in the directory where you specified to create a new vagrant machine).
2. Search for `config.vm.network`. If you didn't setup the file earlier, it should be commented.
3. Change it to look something like this `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.5"`. Here ip address (55.55.55.5) can be any ip address you want.
4. Now logout from the vagrant machine and reload your vagrant machine by this command `vagrant reload`.
5. Again ssh to your vagrant machine and restart your django server by this command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`. Again the port address (80) can be 8000 if you want so.
6. After that, in your browser, enter the following address `55.55.55.5`, and hopefully you should see your webapp.

Now if you would like to go further, you can edit your host file, and add this line

```
55.55.55.5 mynewdomain.com
```

Then in your browser, enter the follow address,

```
mynewdomain.com
```

And you should see your web app. Note that, www is not added in the domain name inside the host file, so only mynewdomain.com can be accessed. You can however add it.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! My guest told me it didn't have access to port 80, so I the runserver command to python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 and accessed the site from my host browser on http://55.55.55.5:8000/.

Comment: My vagrant file has the following content: # -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "pg_config.sh"
  # config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.5"
end

Comment: in my case it's showing Not Found: The requested URL / was not found on this server. error while working on ip adreess when enter in browser. any idea?

Comment: @ImranKhan This should have helped you too. Anyways please confirm that the 1) Needed settings in the vagrantfile are updated, 2) Reoladed the vagrant machine. 3) And finally the server is running.

Comment: I have edit the Vagrantfile, enable the private network and assign ip: 10.10.10.10, then reload the Vagrant then SSH and working in browser by that ip.... but when i created the vhost for that ip not working.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing @Kakar answer, this configuration can also be done using this:

`config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"`

This will assign an IP automatically.

For further reading: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html